# How to use passport-local with graphql

Tags: graphql, passport.js, apollo-server, passport-local

I'm trying to implement GraphQL in my project and I would like to use `passport.authenticate('local')` in my login Mutation

Code adaptation of what I want:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
type Mutation {
      login(userInfo: UserInfo!): User
    }
`

 const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
      login: (parent, args) => { 
        passport.authenticate('local')
        return req.user
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Was `passport` designed mostly for REST/Express?
2. Can I manipulate `passport.authenticate` method (pass username and password to it)?
3. Is this even a common practice or I should stick to some JWT library?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Passport.js is a "Express-compatible authentication middleware". `authenticate` returns an Express middleware function -- it's meant to prevent unauthorized access to particular Express routes. It's not really suitable for use inside a resolver. If you pass your `req` object to your resolver through the context, you can call `req.login` to manually login a user, but you have to verify the credentials and create the `user` object yourself before passing it to the function. Similarly, you can call `req.logout` to manually log out a user. See [here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login) for the docs.

If you want to use Passport.js, the best thing to do is to create an Express app with an authorization route and a callback route for each identify provider you're using (see [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#authenticate-requests) for an example). Then integrate the Express app with your GraphQL service using `apollo-server-express`. Your client app will use the authorization route to initialize the authentication flow and the callback endpoint will redirect back to your client app. You can then add `req.user` to your context and check for it inside resolvers, directives, GraphQL middleware, etc.

However, if you are *only* using local strategy, you might consider dropping Passport altogether and just handling things yourself.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! How common this passport-graphql combination in real life? I have a feeling that I probably should not use passport here.

Answer (score 10):

It took me a while to wrap my head around the combination of GraphQL and Passport. Especially when you want to use the local strategy together with a login mutation makes life complicated. That's why I created a small npm package called [graphql-passport](https://github.com/jkettmann/graphql-passport).

This is how the setup of the server looks like.

```js
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import passport from 'passport';
import { GraphQLLocalStrategy, buildContext } from 'graphql-passport';

passport.use(
  new GraphQLLocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
    // Adjust this callback to your needs
    const users = User.getUsers();
    const matchingUser = users.find(user => email === user.email && password === user.password);
    const error = matchingUser ? null : new Error('no matching user');
    done(error, matchingUser);
  }),
);

const app = express();
app.use(session(options)); // optional
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // if session is used

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req, res }) => buildContext({ req, res, User }),
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });

app.listen({ port: PORT }, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

Now you will have access to passport specific functions and user via the GraphQL context. This is how you can write your resolvers:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    currentUser: (parent, args, context) => context.getUser(),
  },
  Mutation: {
    login: async (parent, { email, password }, context) => {
      // instead of email you can pass username as well
      const { user } = await context.authenticate('graphql-local', { email, password });

      // only required if express-session is used
      context.login(user);

      return { user }
    },
  },
};
```

The combination of GraphQL and Passport.js makes sense. Especially if you want to add more authentication providers like Facebook, Google and so on. You can find more detailed information [in this blog post](https://jkettmann.com/authentication-and-authorization-with-graphql-and-passport/) if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use `passport` unless your goal is to learn about authentication in depth.

I found the most straightforward way to integrate `passport` with GraphQL is to:

- use a JWT strategy
- keep REST endpoints to authenticate and retrieve tokens
- send the token to the GraphQL endpoint and validate it on the backend

Why?

- If you're using a client-side app, token-based auth is the best practice anyways.
- Implementing REST JWT with `passport` is straightforward. You could try to build this in GraphQL as described by @jkettmann but it's way more complicated and less supported. I don't see the overwhelming benefit to do so.
- Implementing JWT in GraphQL is straightforward. See e.g. for [express](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/authentication-and-express-middleware/) or [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)

To your questions:

> Was passport designed mostly for REST/Express?

Not in principle, but you will find most resources about REST and express.

> Is this even a common practice or I should stick to some JWT library?

Common practice is to stick to JWT.

---

More details here: [OAuth2 in NestJS for Social Login (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc)](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/oauth2-in-nestjs-for-social-login-google-facebook-twitter-etc-8b405d570fd2)

Example project bhere: https://github.com/thisismydesign/nestjs-starter

Comment: When you use REST login - how will you pass the HttpOnly cookie (with the JWT token) into the GraphQL playground?

Comment: You can read the cookie on the frontend and pass it to the GraphQL query. More details here: https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/oauth2-in-nestjs-for-social-login-google-facebook-twitter-etc-8b405d570fd2 Example here: https://github.com/thisismydesign/nestjs-starter